# How can I determine if a number entered by a user will be misrepresented when stored as a Single in C#?

Tags: c#, floating-point

I have a datagrid that a user will modify. One column stores a Single preciion float. When a user enters a number longer than 7 digits, the number is displayed in scientific notation, and comparisions to the number become very inaccurate. I would like to warn the user that the number is only being stored approximatley when this happens. Is there any way to determine when a number will be stored properly in a single? The cutoff seems to be about 7 digits. Anything more than that and it is way off.

Comment: Just display the value back after converting it to Single so the feedback is instant.  If you get a lot of complaints then use Double, there's very little point to a Single.  There are 15 significant digits in a double.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need a validate on each cell.

Explain step by step:

Add CellValidating Event To DataGridView by designer or code:

```
  dataGridView1.CellValidating+=dataGridView1_CellValidating;
```

Check that you want in it like this:

```
   private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
        {
            double value = 0;
            if (double.TryParse(e.FormattedValue.ToString(), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out value))
            {
                dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].ErrorText = "";


                //   e.Cancel = false;
            }
            else
            {
                dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].ErrorText = "Bad Input Please Correct It !";
                //   e.Cancel = true;  if you do this the datagrid dont let user go next row
            }
        }
```

If you want correct the value your self do these step too:

Add CellValidated event too:

```
 dataGridView1.CellValidated+=dataGridView1_CellValidated;
```

And do this check in that:

```
  private void dataGridView1_CellValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value == null)
                return;
              double value = 0;
              if (double.TryParse(dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex,e.RowIndex].Value.ToString(), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out value))
              {
                  dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value = Math.Round(value, 2).ToString().Replace("/",".");
              }
        }
```

**Note :** This event occurs each time a cell edit if you want do these on special cell check it before event raise. You can set max Input length for each column to avoid bad input.

Answer (score 1):

You could always just check for yourself by parsing the input and turning it back into a `string`:

```
string s = "0.12345678";
return Single.Parse(s).ToString() == s;
```

Comment: Your first example is meaningless; once it's in a `float`, it has already been corrupted.

Comment: @Rotem That won't work in all cases. As the default ToString will turn something like "12345678f" into "1.234568E+07" even though there is no precision lost. Edit: A quick fix seems to be to cast the float to a decimal before calling ToString.

Answer (score 1):

the second you store any number in a `float` or `double` assume it's no longer 100% accurate, because odds are it's not.  The second you perform any operations on the number, particularly if it's anything other than addition/subtraction, you can be fairly sure there is *some* error.  If you want to know exactly how much error their is, then you start to get into some pretty complex mathematics.